# Unexpected end of mysql in easyphp 13.1

Tags: php, mysql

After a power cut and being forced to reboot my win7 PC I couldn't use mySQL on EasyPHP-DevServer 13.1 anymore, the message: “Unexpected end of mysql”:

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080868/easyphp-devserver-13-1-unexpected-end-of-mysql).

Tried all answers and found @Jessiiem answer to work. As I cannot comment (not enough privileges), I want to put here a little to-do list, so people can save time, if running into the same problem:

1. I found the config file here:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\binaries\conf_files\my.ini
   ```
2. and added:

   ```
   innodb_force_recovery = 1
   ```

   after

   ```
   # Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
   ```
3. Then restarted Easy PHP (Run as Administrator);
4. Uncommented the config file as @Jessiiem suggested:

   ```
   # innodb_force_recovery = 1
   ```

Comment: There are MySQL commands you can run to verify the integrity of your database and repair it if possible.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante - the issue is that the easy php mysql module stops working after forced restart of PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved with the latest upgrade EasyPhp 14.1. download at: easyphp.org